# Using matrices to transform a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let's say we have an equation and we want to transform it by the matrix $A$, where:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, everywhere I've seen has said to find the $x',y'$ vector and substitute the resultant formulas for $x'$ and $y'$ into the original equation. However, I've found I only get the inverse transformation by doing this. Am I correct in thinking I have to find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $x'$ and $y'$ instead?

Comment: Hello @Merlin, welcome on MSE! Could you please tell us what is given and what is unknown? An example would also be helpful!

Comment: @Diglett Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to transform a function (such as y=x) by a matrix (such as the rotation matrix). The x and y are just the variables of the equation and x' and y' are their respective images.

Comment: In short, yes. You’re substituting for $x$ and $y$, so you need to express them in terms of the new variables.

Comment: @amd Ah, that makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: I should probably turn that into an answer, however short.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. You have to substitute something for $x$ and $y$ to transform the equation, so you need to express these old variables in terms of the new variables $x'$ and $y'$. Doing that entails inverting $A$.